# Best way to access to MainWindow control from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm buildind a synchronization tool that's working pretty well, but a noise problem's that I've an heavy method that freeze the UI. 
Now, I know that I can solve this situation with Thread or Task, but in the `Sync();` method I've a lot of access to the UI control.

Actually for access to MainWindow control I've created something like this:

```
public static MainWindow AppWindow;

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   AppWindow = this;
}
```

so from any class I can simply do this: `MainWindow.AppWindow.UIControlName`. As you can imagine, if I use Task or Thread, this solution will become useless. 'cause I'll need to write this for each control:

```
MainWindow.AppWindow.UIControlName.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      (Action)(() => { 
           MainWindow.AppWindow.UIControlName.Content = "Synchronization in progress";
      }));
```

Imagine that I have 20 or more of these lines, the code would become really ugly looking and long, for easy access to the UI control.

Now I wonder what is the best way to call a method asynchronously and return immediately to the caller without blocking the UI.

Without an asynchronous programming for this kind of applications the user experience is not really write home about.

Comment: There are many options. For example - add SetContent method to your window class, do this ugly stuff inside it and just call SetContent("blah") from all other places. Or use async\await - it will return you back to UI thread after async operation is completed and there you can just access window properties as usual.

Comment: @Evk with `async / await` I can access normally to UI thread controls without create an `Action delegate`?

Comment: You are doing WPF wrong. Use Binding.

Comment: @Aron you hint doesn't solve this. You've misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Dillinger You've misunderstood WPF Binding if you think it does not relate to the question. With true MVVM you can update the VM from a background thread and the Binding class marshels the call back to the UI thread. IE You are doing WPF wrong.

Comment: @Aron I know this, I've also use Binding, but I'm not in the main thread I can't update the control

Comment: Also you misunderstand `Task` if you say "cause I'll need to write this for each control:". The default TaskScheduler when running a WPF application will "continue" on the Dispatcher (ie wrap the continuation in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`). You are doing WPF wrong.

Comment: @Dillinger You should NEVER update the control in WPF/MVVM. That is what the Binding class is for. You are inverting the whole "control flow" of WPF. With your business logic dependent on the your View logic, you cannot test the business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either wrap all ugly stuff with dispatcher in separate methods and use those, or use async\await like this:

```
private async void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var result = await LongRunningOperation();
    MainWindow.AppWindow.UIControlName.Content = "Synchronization in progress";
    await YetAnotherLongRunningOperation();
    // update again
}
```

Where LongRunningOperation is:

```
public async Task<SomeResult> LongRunningOperation() {
    // do some stuff here
    return new SomeResult();
}
```

or

```
public async Task LongRunningOperation() {
    // do some stuff
}
```

You can also do it like this:

```
 private async void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var result = await Task.Run(() => LongRunningOperation());
    MainWindow.AppWindow.UIControlName.Content = "Synchronization in progress";
    await YetAnotherLongRunningOperation();
    // update again
}
```

That is because by default before await current synchronization context is captured, and after await this context is restored. In UI applications (like WPF or WinForms) that means if before await you were on UI thread - you will be there after await too, and as such can freely access UI controls.

You might ask - when should you declare your methods async and when just use `Task.Run`. If you do pure CPU computations - you can use `Task.Run`. If you do any IO (file access, network access, etc) - declare your method async and use async methods provided by IO-related classes (like `FileStream.ReadAsync` and such).

For example:

```
private async Task LongRunningOperation() {
    string contents;
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead("some file")) {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs)) {
            contents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
    var downloadedFile = await new WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync("some file url");
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but I've a problem with this. In particular the compiler underline `await Sync();` and display me: `you can not wait void`, this is the declaration of Sync: `public void Sync()`, I also read in the net that's not a good practice declare a method of type `void` and use `async / await`, could you confirm?

Comment: In general it's not good indeed to make async void functions. However, in some cases you have no other choice and event handler is one of such case. You just cannot change signature of button click event handler. Actually this was allowed to make void methods async just to make them work with event handlers and similar situations. Note that button handler is just an example and you might do it differently.

Comment: yes, got it. Anyway, I've also the same problem `cannot wait void`, maybe this can explain better: http://pastebin.com/w5bNW6Mc

Comment: @Dillinger I've expanded my answer a bit. If you want to use async\await - you have to read a bit about what's that really about.

Comment: in this case I should use `async / await` so, I need to access to internet

Comment: @Dillinger expanded a bit more with an example of how you should work with IO in async methods. In general just search for methods which return Task and usually named as XXXAsync and use them instead of usual versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112132/discussion-between-dillinger-and-evk).